# End of Support for Dataflow pipelines written in Python2

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The [Cloud Dataflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/python2-sunset/#dataflow) states that python2 pipelines are no more supported by October 7th.
Does this means that Python2 pipelines will stop working on this date and that I have to port all my pipelines before octobre 7th ?

Or does it mean that my pipelines will keep working but that I should not expect support from the Google Cloud team anymore in case of failure ? In that case, how long before my pipelines will definitely stop working.

I am asking this question because I may not have all my pipelines moved to python 3 by October 7th.

Comment: The link you provided answers your question. **Dataflow cannot guarantee long-term functional support or maintenance of the Python 2 offering.** That means that anytime after October 7th you cannot depend on the support being available. IOW, they could stop it completely on October 8th or 10th or November 1st o any other day after October 7th.

Answer (score 1):

Though Python 2 pipelines might not be rejected on October 8th, I would not expect them to work long after that (e.g. probably within a week or at most two), at least not without action on your part. If you don't anticipate being able to fully be on Python 3 by that time, you could try reaching out to Google directly to try to get an extension for your projects (though even this might not be for long).

Comment: See also https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/using-unsupported-sdks